# Coffeescript single co-ordinate of turtle

Tags: coffeescript, coordinates

I know that

```
co=getxy()
```

will store the x and y co-ordinates of the turtle as the variable

```
co
```

but is it possible to find and store just **one** of the co-ordinates. E.g.

```
x
```

**OR**

```
y
```

Any help is appretiated, as I cannot find any references to doing this.

->Alternatively, can I take the

```
(x,y)
```

and convert it to

```
x
```

**OR**

```
y
```

**EDIT:** With turtle at (-500, 50) I did

```
co=getxy()
co-=50
write co
```

with no success. It retured NaN.

*(By the way, this is being created using* Pencilcode.net *if that makes any difference.)*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured out the answer myself, inspired by '@mu is too short'. Basiclly, this is the code:

```
jumpto -500,50
[co_x,co_y]=getxy()
write co_x
write co_y
```

I assume that Coffeescript figures out the co-ords are two pieces of data, and splits it between the two variables, as opposed to cramming them both into one.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably `getxy` is return an array of two elements with the x-coordinate in the first position and the y-coordinate in the second. That means that you could work with `co` as array:

```
co = getxy()
co[0] -= 50
write co[0]
```

or use a [destructured assignment](http://coffeescript.org/#destructuring) to unpack the array:

```
[x,y] = getxy()
x -= 50
write x
```

If `getxy` returns an object with `x` and `y` properties then you could say:

```
co = getxy()
co.x -= 50
write co.x
```

or destructure it like this:

```
{x,y} = getxy()
x -= 50
write x
```

Comment: Thanks, but this simply doesn't work (for me). The first two reply '-50' and the bottom two reply 'NaN'. Thanks for trying though, as I am completely clueless! :(

Comment: The first one seemed to work just fine for you. I added the second because you didn't mention what `getxy` returned, hence the "If `getxy` returns an object..." note.